# Recursive handling of operators in python parsec

Tags: python, parsing, parsec

I'm trying to learn how to use [parsec](https://github.com/sighingnow/parsec.py).

I'm struggling with how to handle recursive definitions to handle something like the addition operator in infix form.

I know why the below code doesn't work, but I don't know how to fix it.

```py
from parsec import *

test_strings = (
        ('1', 1),
        ('123', 123),
        ('(( 123))', 123),
        ('((1+2))', 3),
        ('1+2+3', 6),
        ('1+2+3+4', 10),
        ('(4 + 5 + 2)', 11),
        ('(4 + 5) + 2', 9),
        ('2 + (4 + 5)', 11),
        ('2 + (5 + (3+4))', 14),
        ('2 + ((3+4) + 5)', 14), #these don't work
        ('2 + (5 + (3+4) + 5)', 19), #these don't work
)


whitespace = regex(r'\s*', re.MULTILINE)
lexeme = lambda p: p << whitespace

lparen = lexeme(string('('))
rparen = lexeme(string(')'))
no_paren = many(none_of('()'))

plus = lexeme(string('+'))

number = lexeme(regex(r'\d+').parsecmap(int))

@generate
def addition():
    e1 = yield braced | number
    yield plus
    e2 = yield expr
    return e1 + e2

@generate
def braced():
    yield lparen
    es = yield braced ^ expr
    yield rparen
    return es


expr = braced ^ addition ^ number


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for s, expected in test_strings:
        print(f'testing expression {s}')
        res = expr.parse(s)
        assert res == expected, f'for {s}, expected {expected}, got {res}'
```

`addition` is obviously wrong but if I attempt to have the left operand (e1) be of type `expr`, then we'll get infinite recursion. This makes sense because this recursive definition doesn't consume anything on each invocation.

The solution I'm looking for is something that can scale to handle nested expressions which will be more complex once I have this problem sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it to work with these changes:

```py
@generate
def addition():
    e1 = yield (braced | number)
    yield plus
    e2 = yield expr
    return e1 + e2

@generate
def braced():
    yield lparen
    es = yield expr
    yield rparen
    return es

expr = addition ^ (braced | number)
```